# Error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int') on my code

Tags: c++, syntax

When I run this code, I receive the following error:

> invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

How can I clear this up?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

void multiplyFive (int &x, int y, int *z){
    int d = 5 * x;
    int e = 5 * y;
    int f = 5 * *z;
    cout << d << " " << e << " " << f << endl;
}

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    int *b = &a;
    int &c = *b;

    multiplyFive (a, b, *c);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clangs error message is a bit more helpful:

```
<source>:19:21: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
multiplyFive (a, b, *c);
                    ^~
```

`c` is a reference to an `int` not a pointer, you cannot dereference it via `*`.

It seems like you mixed up 2nd and 3rd parameters to `multiplyFive`, because the next error you will receive is that `b` is a `int*` but `multiplyFive` expects a `int` in its place.